# Getting the error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When using the context API and destructuring the children in the AppProvider, getting the following error;
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'.

I am trying to pass the state of Todo but getting the error, and the main.tsx is thowring error when I am wrapping the AppProvider on the App component.

"Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.\n  Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props"

context.tsx:

```
import { TodoContextType, ITodo } from "./@types/todo";

export const AppContext = React.createContext<TodoContextType | null>(null);

const AppProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({children}) => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState<ITodo[]>([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "to do 1",
      desc: "to do",
      status: false,
      dLine: 4,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "to do 2",
      desc: "to do",
      status: true,
      dLine: 1,
    },
  ]);
  const saveTodo = (todos: ITodo) => {
    const newTodo: ITodo = {
      id: Math.random(),
      title: todos.title,
      desc: todos.desc,
      status: false,
      dLine: todos.dLine,
    };
    setTodo([...todo, newTodo]);
  };

  const updateTodo=(id:number){
   todo.filter((todos:ITodo)=>{
    if(todos.id===id){
     todos.status = true;
     setTodo([...todo]);
    }
   })
  }

  return (
   <AppContext.Provider value={{todo, saveTodo, updateTodo}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  )
};


export default AppProvider;
```

todo.d.ts:

```
  id: number;
  title: string;
  desc: string;
  status: boolean;
  dLine: number;
  // children: React.ReactNode;
}

export type TodoContextType = {
  todos: ITodo[];
  saveTodo: (todo: ITodo) => void;
  updateTodo: (id: number) => void;
};
```

main.tsx:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import AppProvider from "./context";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <App />
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uh, perhaps you meant `React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type seems to be wrong

```js
import { TodoContextType, ITodo } from "./@types/todo";

export const AppContext = React.createContext<TodoContextType | null>(null);

const AppProvider: React.FC<{children: React.ReactNode}> = ({children}) => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState<ITodo[]>([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "to do 1",
      desc: "to do",
      status: false,
      dLine: 4,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "to do 2",
      desc: "to do",
      status: true,
      dLine: 1,
    },
  ]);
  const saveTodo = (todos: ITodo) => {
    const newTodo: ITodo = {
      id: Math.random(),
      title: todos.title,
      desc: todos.desc,
      status: false,
      dLine: todos.dLine,
    };
    setTodo([...todo, newTodo]);
  };

  const updateTodo=(id:number){
   todo.filter((todos:ITodo)=>{
    if(todos.id===id){
     todos.status = true;
     setTodo([...todo]);
    }
   })
  }

  return (
   <AppContext.Provider value={{todo, saveTodo, updateTodo}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  )
};


export default AppProvider;
```